# Solidity Security

Tags: security

I'm new in security of ICO and smart contracts. Trying to find bugs in verified contracts. I believe I found some problems in 0x42dB5Bfe8828f12F164586AF8A992B3a7B038164 but I dont know how to withdrawal. Do I need to create a transaction by myself?

Comment: Hi there. It's not too clear what you're asking. Are you asking us how to drain the funds held by the contract...?

Comment: How did you come across this and similar contracts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HaHa - very sneaky.

### ***Warning***

To anyone tempted to mess with [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x42dB5Bfe8828f12F164586AF8A992B3a7B038164#code) - i.e. exploit the apparent flaw: you will likely lose your Ether.

Explanation follows.

It looks like there is a pretty tempting vulnerability in the `withdrawal()` function: when you send the function more than `Limit` Wei then it will send you the whole balance of the contract - the amount you sent plus the 0.36 Eth already there. Instant profit!

**However**, there is this innocent-looking, but nonetheless peculiar `delegatecall` to a `logEvent()` function in a different contract. To cut a long story short, this **does not** log an event. It actually sneakily modifies the value of the `adr` storage variable so that it no longer points to `msg.sender`. So the contract balance will not be sent back to you by the `adr.send(this.balance)` call, it will be sent somewhere else, since `adr` is no longer equal to `msg.sender`.

It's a bit obfuscated, but it looks like the delegated call to the `email.logEvent()` contract function causes `adr` to be set to the contract's own address: i.e. it sends all the Ether (including that which you sent) to itself. Only the contract owner (0x46Feeb381e90f7e30635B4F33CE3F6fA8EA6ed9b) can actually withdraw the Eth.

Comment: The first line in your answer implies that the dude who posted the question is trying to pull a scam. Did you really intend to imply this?

Comment: Ah, I see. Very good :-) +1

Comment: I'm not a scammer, I'm researching the contracts only. Thank you a lot for the awareness!

Comment: @Mike N. In that case, welcome and feel free to mark the answer accepted. Hopefully I've explained sufficiently why it's not a good idea to have anything to do with this contract if you don't own it.

Comment: Sure! How can I accept it? By the way I've looked though other contracts and find several similar! 0x62d5c4a317b93085697cfb1c775be4398df0678c and 0x477D1EE2F953A2F85dbEcBcB371c2613809eA452 . Probably there are much more. Can we block them somehow?

Comment: [What to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) tl;dr - click the check mark alongside the answer you want to accept.

Comment: "Can we block them somehow?" - this is the blockchain. Despite the name, nothing can be blocked. It's a feature. If people lose Eth trying to hack the hackers, I'm not really that sympathetic.

Comment: Sorry for the additional questions. I've deployed the contract code locally. But as I dont have the source code of different contract which is called. How can I deploy this contract in test network? And these two other contracts are seemed a bit different. I'd like to test them too... Do you debug the transactions in Remix?

Comment: The Tx that created the `email` contract is [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2429de711d3b07025c1be2468fc2749782e3a195f6b1f6e671edfcf67181ea7e). Just copy and paste the bytecode into whatever deployment tool you use. You then need to change the address in the other contract to point to the new address of `email`. I use a decompiler I wrote and a lot of scribbling on bits of paper to analyse things. Remix is good if there is an existing Tx to trace, but there wasn't in this case.

Comment: Hi, It seems someone has done the withdrawal from both contracts above. Could someone explain how it was done?

Comment: It looks like someone is just kidding )) Another one ) 0x47000dE9Ac92E29d4Fee617732fFEedc306Bd10E ... So how can I check on the possibility to take the ether? How do you call this function from another contract?

Comment: @Mike N. The author killed the contract themselves. Your follow-ups would be better asked as fresh questions than buried here.

Comment: Ok! Moved discussion here - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34708/security-in-contracts